# Ao fazer o diagrama de classes é necessário adicionar todos os métodos e atributos?

Tags: java, uml, diagrama-de-classes

Tenho várias classes que possuem diversos atributos e métodos. Ao fazer o diagrama de classes é necessário adicionar todos os métodos e atributos? Existe alguma regra ou consenso sobre a criação desses?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Depende. Você quer fazer certo ou quer fazer de qualquer jeito? Se quer fazer certo então precisa. Nem deveria ter que pensar nisso. O propósito de fazer UML é documentar tudo. Se for para fazer pela metade então pra que fazer?

Na verdade por que está fazendo UML? Se não souber porque e esse motivo não for muito bom, não puder provar que está te dando alguma vantagem, por que fazê-lo? As pessoas estão fazendo muita coisa automaticamente porque viram outras fazendo, elas nem sabem porque estão fazendo aquilo, se tem vantagem.

Um exemplo está em outra resposta. As pessoas usam *getters* e *setters* sem pensar. Quase sempre o seu uso está errado, mas tem tanta gente fazendo errado que já parece que é certo. Os mais radicais em orientação a objeto dizem que eles nunca devem ser usados porque são métodos que não tem um propósito específico, ele só serve para encapsular estado, e métodos assim não deveria existir. Os mais pragmáticos consideram que eles só estão encapsulando estado sem ganho algum. A maioria das pessoas não conseguem responder porque criam *getters* e *setters*, apenas estão fazendo o que viram outros fazendo (e que fique claro, se for para ter no código, tem que ter no UML, senão esta representação é equivocada, a crítica aqui é ter no código, não só no UML). UML é para fazer pensar no que está fazendo antes de fazer, é para ter certeza se precisa daquilo, se não falta nada, se tudo vai encaixar bem. Quando faz automaticamente não precisa de UML.

UML é burocracia, se não for para fazer certo, não faça. Em outra resposta diz que deve por tudo ou só parte dependendo de as pessoas vão precisar saber se o sistema terá aquilo. Mas é para alguém não saber? Você vai colocar no sistema uma coisa e documentar outra? Que sentido isso faz? UML já é criticada porque ela não costuma ser [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Agora ainda vai explicitar que eles devem ser independentes?

As pessoas precisam pensar no que fazem, não seguir regras bobas que elas não sabem porque foram inventadas.

Como usou *tag* de linguagem tenho que dizer que os termos usados estão corretos para UML, mas [para Java não estão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu saiba não existe uma regra geral para todos os casos. Isso vai depender muito de quem vai precisar dos seus diagramas, pois UML é uma notação usada na comunicação entre os desenvolvedores. Desenvolvedores tanto aqueles que estão colaborando com você agora e também aqueles que podem continuar o projeto no futuro.

Portanto, é preciso analisar se você ou alguém vai precisar saber se o sistema tem determinado método ou atributo e qual a sua função no sistema. Por isso que muitos falam que *getters* e *setters* não precisam ser colocados, pois não são relevantes para maioria das pessoas.